# Command to delete blank lines in txt file doesn't work with variable in file path

Tags: windows-10, powershell-5.0

Command to delete blank lines in List.txt file, doesn't work when I use variable `$env:username`.

Works: Using CMG username in file path.

```
$linblk = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\List.txt');$linblk = $linblk.Trim();[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText('C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\List.txt', $linblk)
```

Does not work: Using `$env:username` variable in file path:

```
$linblk = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\List.txt');$linblk = $linblk.Trim();[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText('C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\List.txt', $linblk)
```

```
Exception when calling "ReadAllText" with "1" argument(s): "The given path format is not supported."
No line:1 character:1
+ $linblk = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('C:\Users\$env:username\Deskt ...


+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How to make the command accept the variable `$env:username` ?

**EDITED**:
so it worked: command in answer @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style

```
$linblk = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Users\$($env:username)\Desktop\List.txt");
$linblk = $linblk.Trim();
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Users\$($env:username)\Desktop\List.txt", $linblk)
```

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style Didn't work, message: `The given path format is not supported.` `On line:1 character:1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\List.txt")` for the syntax to encapsulate the parameter value in double quotes.

### PowerShell

```
$linblk = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\List.txt");
$linblk = $linblk.Trim();
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\List.txt", $linblk)
```

### PowerShell (Another Variation)

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\List.txt"
$file | % {$_.Trim()} | Set-Content "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\List.txt"
```

### Supporting Resource

- [Get-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)
- [Set-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/set-content.html)

Comment: It didn't give an error, but it also didn't delete the blank line at the end of the file

Comment: @Clamarc Refresh again and use double quotes on the first command examples. That variation is strange because it works for me. In any case, refresh the post and see the update I made just now using double quotes for the command you were originally trying.

Comment: TrimEnd() didn't work either, but the double quote in the first command did!. thanks!

Comment: @Clamarc No worries, I just updated my edit and removed the subexpression operator detail as it wasn't needed. It was just double quotes after all. I modified the `trimend()` back to `trim()` as it does work for me in case someone else finds it helpful. See latest refresh again.

Comment: hi Vomit, the `$linblk` command works, but I noticed that it changes the column name special character `Música` to `Mï¿ ½sica`, the `ú` special character, is changed to `ï¿ ½` Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @Clamarc That is likely related to needing to use the `-Encoding` to unicode or some other encoding you need for those characters. Both the `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` commands contain those so you might have to play with it a bit to figure out what example combination you need with each command. Also `Get-Content` has a `-Raw` parameter too that may be helpful with that problem. Check out: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: Look over https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2, and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.2 as well.

Comment: Ok, Add-content worked with -Encoding utf8... again, thanks for the help!